# iptables: Get a List of all Source IPs

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, iptables

I was looking for a way to get a list of all source IPs in a iptables chain.

Or is there a way to get the source column of the

```
iptables -nvL INPUT
```

output somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
iptables -nvL INPUT | awk '{print $8}'
```

Which will just print the 8th column from `iptables`

If you want to drop any sources that are 0.0.0.0/0 then you can use a condition before the print block:

```
iptables -nvL INPUT | awk '$8!="0.0.0.0/0"{print $8}'
```